# NSWorkspace doesn't send resign notification

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

I have launchd agent that tracks when user has active session.

To achieve this I subscribe for `NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActiveNotification` / `NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification`notifications and they are doing their job well most of the times.

But sometimes, during fast user switching, both notifications are delivered when user comes back, so I cannot guess when user resigned session. This happens really often when system lacks of resources.

This behaviour repeats if I run my app not just like a agent but like a terminal program also. Process priority (`nice()`) doesn't help also.

Is there any way to resolve problems with `NSWorkspace` or achieve same behaviour with other technology?